# Java ArrayList.removeAll(), but for indices

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
ArrayList<String>.removeAll(ArrayList<Integer>)
```

With the `ArrayList<Integer>` being the indices that I want deleted. I know that I could iterate through the indices list and use `remove(index)`, but I was wondering if there is a one-command way of doing so.

I know how to put this iteration into one line, my question is, if there is a way implemented by oracle.

Comment: There is no such built-in method. However, you can easily create such a method by simply iterating over the indices, calling the ordinary `remove` method for each index individually. All possible answers to your question will show such an approach.

Comment: @Zabuza thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Stream` to iterate through the indices to remove.  However, take care to remove the highest index first, to avoid shifting other elements to remove out of position.

```
public void removeIndices(List<String> strings, List<Integer> indices)
{
     indices.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
         .forEach(strings::remove);
}
```

For removing from a list of `String`s this will work, calling the proper `remove(int)` method.  If you were to try this on a `List<Integer>`, then you will have to avoid calling `remove(E)` by calling `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` before calling `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8 Streams.

For example:

```
IntStream.of(7,6,5,2,1).forEach(i->list.remove(i));
```

If the indices are given as a `List<Integer>`, you can do:

```
indexList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).forEach(i->list.remove(i));
```

Note that I preferred to use an `IntStream` and not a `Stream<Integer>`, since if you use a `Stream<Integer>` for the indices, if the list from which you wish to remove elements is itself a `List<Integer>`, calling `remove(Integer)` will remove the element whose value is that `Integer`, not the element whose index is that `Integer`.

Comment: Isn't this just another way of iterating through the second arrayList?

Comment: @AzogtheDebugger I don't know how you expect to do it otherwise. It would iterate anyway at some point of the stack.

Comment: You probably want to have the list in reverse numerical order, because index 2 will point to a different item after index 1 is removed.

Comment: I might as well do `indexList.forEach((index) -> { list.remove(i); })` at this point, no need to use a stream

Comment: @AzogtheDebugger I preferred to use `int` indices instead of `Integer` indices, to make the solution more general (otherwise it won't work if `list` was a `List<Integer>`).

Comment: You can use **method references** to make the code more compact: `i -> list.remove(i)` is then just `list::remove`

Answer (score 0):

I still get warnings with the above by @rgettman. To avoid the warnings and to make sure you are using the right remove method you can do this.  I know some people hate lambdas but I think this is clearer than the extra mapToInt

```
    public void removeIndices(List<OtherObject> other, List<Integer> indices)
    {
       indices.stream()
             .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
             .forEach(i->other.remove(i.intValue()));
    }
```